# why commutator requires so many slots

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor, winding

At a given point of time, current in any wire in armature winding is either positive or in negative direction, then why there is a need of so many slots in commutator? doesn't a two slot commutator suffice?
Or Aren't the any given winding wire is not powered all the time? if so, Why?

Answer (score 2):

The role of commutator is to keep rotor flux at right angle with respect to stator flux \$T_m=T_{max}sin(\phi)\$. with higher number of slots the angle keeps the 90 degrees. With lower number of slots, the angle is bouncing, making the torque ripple higher.

Comment: I mean, keeping the number of winding and solenoid constant as now, why cant one switch the current direction in them with two or four switches? Please explain the concept of bouncing of angle

Comment: The commutators _are_ the switches. They keep perfect synchronisation with the rotation of the rotor.

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't a two slot commutator suffice?

[image]

*Figure 1. A DC motor with two commutator segments. Source: [Electrical4U](http://www.electrical4u.com/working-or-operating-principle-of-dc-motor/).*

- As drawn in Figure 1 this motor has maximum torque as both conductors are in the magnetic field and current is flowing in opposite directions on each side of the axis of rotation.
- If the rotor rotates 90° the two currents will be placed in *the same magnetic field* and the rotational force on each conductor will cancel out giving no torque.
- In addition, note that with only two segments the brushes will tend to short out on the transition from one segment to the other.

Adding more commutator segments and coils means that one or more coils is always positioned for maximum torque.

> Or Aren't the any given winding wire is not powered all the time?

I don't understand this question.

Comment: we see that in a commutator not all slots are touched by the brushes at a time, does that mean that the winding connected to remaining slots are not powered at that time?

Comment: No. Look  up lap winding and wave winding. All the windings are connected.